# Column value will increment and reset for changes in another two columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe where I want to keep on increasing the value until `val` changes and when `id` changes reset the `count` value

```
data = [['p1',1],
        ['p1',1],
        ['p1',2],
        ['p2',3],
        ['p2',5],
        ['p3',1],
        ['p3',2],
        ['p3',1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data,columns = ['id','val'])
```

Desired output

```
       id val  count
    0  p1   1      1
    1  p1   1      1
    2  p1   2      2
    3  p2   3      1
    4  p2   5      2
    5  p3   1      1
    6  p3   2      2
    7  p3   1      3
```

I have get till here

```
df['count'] = (df.val.diff() != 0).cumsum()
```

This only change when `val` column changes but doesn't reset when `id` column changes

Comment: Are your ids always ordered to appear in groups, or can `p1` occur again at the bottom where you would need to consider it separately from the block at the top?

Comment: no p1 will not occur again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution based on Your initial try:

```
df['count'] = df.assign(dif = (df.val.diff() != 0)).groupby(['id']).dif.cumsum()
```

result:

```
   id  val  count
0  p1    1    1.0
1  p1    1    1.0
2  p1    2    2.0
3  p2    3    1.0
4  p2    5    2.0
5  p3    1    1.0
6  p3    2    2.0
7  p3    1    3.0
```

Taking into account comments of @ALollz, alternative solution:

```
df['count'] = df.assign(dif = (df.val.diff() != 0).astype(int)).groupby(['id']).dif.apply(lambda x : x.cumsum().rank(method='dense'))
```

Now counting begins always from 1 within groups.

Answer (score 7):

you can try `groupby+transform` with a `lambda`

```
df['count'] = df.groupby("id")['val'].transform(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum())
```

---

```
print(df)

   id  val  count
0  p1    1      1
1  p1    1      1
2  p1    2      2
3  p2    3      1
4  p2    5      2
5  p3    1      1
6  p3    2      2
7  p3    1      3
```

Comment: transform with shift is nice ~

Answer (score 2):

I will do

```
df.val.diff().ne(0).cumsum().groupby(df.id).transform(lambda x : x.factorize()[0]+1)
Out[149]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    1
6    2
7    3
Name: val, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df2 = df.groupby(['id','val']).size().reset_index() #get unique combinations
df2 = df2.groupby('id').val.cumcount()
```

Read more about cumcount in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html)

Comment: How does this answer the question ?